# How to Compare K8s Deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I have an app which has got few services(10) having Deployment, Gateway, Ingress, HPA, VS, secrets, crons and others

File structure of this look something like

```
kuberenets/Dev [containing all yamls only for Dev env]
              service1/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
             service2/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others

kuberenets/Prod [containing all yamls only for Prod env]
              service1/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
           service2/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
```

Now i have restructered it so that i could move few things in common, so now my folder structure look something like this

```
kuberenets/common [containing all yamls which are common b/w envs]
              service1/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
             service2/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others


kuberenets/Dev [containing yamls changes which are just needed for dev, and they are patch to common folder ]
              service1/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
             service2/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others

kuberenets/Prod [containing yamls changes which are just needed for prod, and they are patch to common folder]
              service1/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
             service2/
                       deployment.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       gateway.yaml
                       secret.yaml
                       ... others
```

Now to review whether the deployments have same configuration from both the structure its difficult to understand from a git difference , so far i got to know we could generate the single deployment yaml for a service and can compare , is this the right approach to compare things here ? Or is there any tool which i can make use of it here ?

Comment: there's kubediff, but I haven't used it tbh, link: https://github.com/weaveworks/kubediff